# WKT precision/rounding using shapely?

Tags: python, well-known-text, shapely

I am using Shapely's wkt.dumps function to get WKT from geometry objects.

How do I limit the precision of the coordinates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Shapely 1.3 you can give `dumps()` a rounding_precision keyword arg:

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Point
>>> from shapely.wkt import dumps
>>> dumps(Point(1.00000000000001, 0.0))
'POINT (1.00000000000001 0)'
>>> dumps(Point(1.00000000000001, 0.0), rounding_precision=4)
'POINT (1 0)'
```